Is it possible for a DACPAC built from a database project to include the build objects from related database projects?
I have a database project in my Visual Studio solution that I'm attempting to treat as my master database project. In the same solution are three other database projects, all of which define separate schemas and their respective tables. The master database project includes database references to all three child database projects. My goal is to be able to build a DACPAC from the master project and have that DACPAC include the schemas and tables from all three child projects.
Interestingly enough, when I publish the master project from Visual Studio, the resulting database includes all the build objects from all three child projects. When I attempt to do the same thing using the DACPAC generated by the project build, the database is completely empty - nothing from any of the referenced projects is included.
Is there some trick to getting this to work? Or is this just an inherent limitation of DACPACs/database projects in Visual Studio?
For reference, I am using Visual Studio Professional 2022 to hit my local instance of SQL Server 2019. All my database projects are configured to use SQL Server 2019.
